# Using a Tab Bar App with a Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I want to use a Tab Bar App with a `UINavigationController`.
I followed [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFNtD098Bbk). It looked nice and easy, but I am new to Objective-C.

When I do the what is shown at 2:50 in the video, I get these results: http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/761392Capturede769cran20110515a768024124.png
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/461473Capturede769cran20110515a768024130.png

The other thing in the video is he made an example for one item. What if I want two items in the navigation bar? Is it correct to have a separate navigation controller for each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking whether if you have a tab-bar-based UI with navigation possible in each tab, you should have a UINavigationController under each tab.

Yes.

Comment: Ok thank you . this is my second question .
Why when i drop item home to the item (picture 1) like he do in the video in minute 2,50 , it dont work ?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct and required that you make a separate UINavigationController for each tab.